# insert statement inside stored procedure failing

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a oracle stored procedure and creating an error log table if that doesn't exist.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
       INTO v_count  
       FROM all_tables  
       WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ERROR_LOG';  
       IF v_count       =0 THEN  
     cr_table := 'CREATE TABLE ERROR_LOG ( ERROR_LOG_ID  NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON         NULL AS IDENTITY, IDENTIFIER VARCHAR2(100), ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(1000),created_by varchar2(100        ), created_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT systimestamp )';  
execute immediate cr_table;
```

then issuing an insert statement below in the code as

```
INSERT
INTO error_log
(
identifier,
error_message,
created_by
)
VALUES
(
v_identifier,
'Success',
v_user
);
```

But the SP is throwing compilation error with

> PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

If I create the table manually, offline, and compile then it works. 
any help?

Comment: Just for future reference - to use DDL/SCL statements in stored procedures - bad practice.

Comment: That is not the correct approach if you are using it in a distributed environment. What you should do is deploy the create table script ( maybe dynamic ) separately in all environments. Your main procedure that contains the `insert into error_log` must be followed and compiled only on the success of the execution of ddl file. If you are not yet practising something like in your environment, it's time to change it for good.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `execute immediate` to create a table, **it exists in the PL/SQL context, not in SQL context**, you have to execute the INSERT by using execute immedation too.
Or you have to make the insert inside an other BEGIN.. END block.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

The table doesn't exist when the code is compiled.  Hence, you are getting a compile-time error.  At compilation time, Oracle doesn't know that the table will exist when executed.

One solution is to use dynamic SQL for the `insert` as well.

A better solution is to set up the database with the appropriate tables *before* the code can ever be executed.  Creating permanent tables dynamically in conditional code is usually a sign of a poorly designed application.

Comment: Well, this is a distributed SP , going to be compiled and executed at many customer systems. I can't write a create table before SP, because the table may or may not exist at that time

Comment: Your deployment scripts need to handle the case where the table already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the stored procedure, please create a view or table where you are going to insert the values using the SP. So it will avoid the compiler error in the run time.